# How does the push function work in a stacked linkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, nodes

This is my teacher's sample code:

```
public void push(T item){
        node<T> newNode = new node<T>(item);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;

    }
```

This is what I understand:
I create a new node called newNode. This sets the data value of the new node to the item and the next points to nothing (null).

Then I say that the new node points to the node next to it which is called head. Then I make the head of the list newNode.

This is what I don't get: 
What happens to the previous node that was the head? How does it know to go after the newNode and not just disappear and get out of the list?

For example, if 5 was the head and 6 was the newNode, then 6 would point to 5 as the node after it. But then we say that the head, which is 5, is also 6? So what happens to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a bit of a strange answer but maybe it would help to take a look how the pointers are being set up:

So the original list would look like this:

```
linkedList -(head)-> node1 -(next)-> node2 -(next)-> etc.
```

Then you make a new node: `node<T> newNode = new node<T>(item);`

```
node3 -(next)-> null    
linkedList -(head)-> node1 -(next)-> node2 -(next)-> etc.
```

Then you make the new node point to your old head: `newNode.next = head;`

```
node3 -(next)-> node1 -(next)-> node2 -(next)-> etc.  
linkedList -(head)-> node1 -(next)-> node2 -(next)-> etc.
```

And then you change your head pointer to new node: `head = newNode;`

```
linkedList -(head)-> node3 -(next)-> node1 -(next)-> node2 -(next)-> etc.
```

Comment: thank u! so node3 is not part of the linked list until you says head=newNode?

Comment: so head is a pointer like next? :o why can't you say "head.next = newNode"

Comment: Yeah head is also just just a pointer @suikyo. Any variable that isn't a [primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is just a pointer.

Comment: _why can't you say "head.next = newNode"_ ? You can say that, but then the new node's `next` wouldn't be pointing anywhere. It's not a bad way to clear the LinkedList though.

Comment: newNode.next = head; here node3 points to node1. but after that u said head = newNode and you just made the "head" pointer point to node3 and node3 point to node1. if node3 points to node1, doesn't it automatically become the head? I see it redundant to say again "head = newNode".

Comment: _if node3 points to node1, doesn't it automatically become the head?_ No it doesn't because you've still never changed the head pointer. The only way a pointer will change if a line of code explicitly changes it. @suikyo

Answer (score 1):

When you First create a Node onto the stack you place the last one on top which is the head. So first your Example was place 5 onto the stack so 5 its next is point to null and is the head of the stack. Which is what you understand.  When you Place 6 onto the stack its nextNode.next is pointing to the address of where head is currently is which is the node 5 in this case. Then the head will then point to the address of the node 6.

So 6 is still pointing to the previous head which was 5.

Hope this helped

Comment: thanks! what do u mean by "Then the head will then point to the address of the node 6." You said that 6 is pointing to the address of the head which is 5.